# How Can I Replace Text Between single quotes and bracket in notepad++?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to replace text between single quote and bracket with a text

eg :

```
insert into tab1(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5) values('ab',228,6,'zbc','2015-09-22 12:31:11.797541000')
```

to

```
insert into tab1(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5) values('ab',228,6,'zbc',INSERT_NEWTEXT)
```

Answer (score 1):

Find for `'[^']*'\)$`

and replace by `'NEW_TEXT'\)`

The above regex finds a single quote followed by 0 or more characters (which is not a single quote) followed by the closing single quote and the ending round bracket (which must be present at the end of line using `$` anchor)

Comment: `)` in `'NEW_TEXT')` should also be escaped .